# InStrRev Not Giving Correct Results

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an Access database where I'm importing book/journal publication data from JabRef in a CSV format.
When I import the data to Access one of the odd things that happens is that the page numbers are given two hyphens in between them, so the data in the "pages" column in Access would look something like "200--213"

I need to be able to count the number of pages that are referenced.

In order to do this I do the following in unbound text boxes on the form:

I find the length of the string in the "pages" column (have to rename the pages variable as it's a reserved name to pagesset):  PLen = Len([pagesset])

I find the number of characters that happen from the left up to the "--": LPageVar = InStr([pagesset],"--")

I find the number of characters that happen from the right up to the "--": RPageVar = InStrRev([pagesset],"--")

I find the actual page number on the left side of the "--":  LVal = Left([pagesset],[LPageVar]-1)

I find the actual page number on the right side of the "--":  RVal = Right([pagesset],[RPageVar]-1)

I calculate the number of pages that appear:  Pgcnt = RVal - LVal

Everything seems to work... except when the "InStrRev" hits an item that increments the number by  the 10 or 100 spot, like this:  "7--11", "7--23", or "92--101" as opposed to this: "102--123" or "103--110" (which causes no issues).  When it hits these shorter pagethe RPageVar is too low by 1.

For each of these items on the right, RVal seems to drop the first character... so for "7--11" last page is reported as 1 or for "7--23" it would report the last page as 3 or "92--101" the last page is reported as 01.  This causes these particular page counts to be negative.

Does anyone have an idea as to why I'm getting this behavior?

Comment: How many pages in the range "1--2"?

Comment: I believe your code calculates the pages correctly.  There would be 2 pages in the range "1--2".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a different approach which is less confusing for me;  not sure if it will be less confusing for anyone else, though.

```vb
? PageCount("200--213")
 14 
? PageCount("7--11")
 5 

Function PageCount(ByVal pIn As String) As Long
    Dim astrPageRange() As String
    astrPageRange = Split(pIn, "--")
    PageCount = (Val(astrPageRange(1)) - Val(astrPageRange(0))) + 1
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

`InStrRev()` searches from the end of the string, but the location it returns is relative to the *beginning* of the string, not the end. So,

```vbs
s = "this is a test--1"
Debug.Print InStrRev(s,"--")
```

displays 15, and

```vbs
Right("this is a test--1",15)
```

is obviously not going to isolate the "1" at the end of the string. That would be done with

```vbs
Mid(s,InStrRev(s,"--")+2)
```

or, in the case where there is only one instance of `"--"` in the string

```vbs
Mid(s,InStr(s,"--")+2)
```

would also work.

Comment: Thanks Gord,  This helped me understand the issue at hand... ultimately I went with HansUp's answer, as it super simplified the process.